# Automation Studio - Will Fire Event wait for SQL query to complete?

Tags: automationstudio

I have an automation in which I have to run an SQL Query to update a DE, 
and then notify Journey Builder for the eventually added contacts.

**2 questions please:**

1. Provided I do it in a one step automation:

**Step 1**

a. SQL Query Activity

b. Fire Event

Will the fire event wait for the SQL Query Activity to finish, which can take a few minutes, or just to launch?

2. Same question if I do it in two steps:

**Step 1**

SQL Query Activity

**Step 2**

Fire Event

Will the fire event wait? or do I explicitly need to add a Wait Activity between the two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do this in two steps. The query will run in step 1. When the query is finished, then and only then will the automation move to step 2 - firing the journey.

If you put multiple activities in a step, the activities won't wait for each other to finish. If you need something to wait for another activity tofinish, then you'll need to put it in another step.

Comment: Awesome! @Harley 
That's what I thought, 
how do we go about Wait Activities? Is there away to assure a SQL Query runs every 15 minutes within an hour?